# How to Install and Use Cassandra Reaper for Apache Cassandra 2.2.X version

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

We are using Cassandra 2.2.x version in production and currently we are manually triggering the repairs on each node. So we are planning to automate repairs using Cassandra Reaper. I don't see much documentation on it. Can anyone please list the steps how to configure the reaper in multi dc environment and use it?

Comment: http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/

Comment: Thanks understood. Quick question sorry if is dumb, in our environment we have 10 nodes, installing Reaper on single node is enough right? to repair the entire cluster? or do we need to install reaper on each node i.e on 10 nodes?

Comment: do you get the solution??

Comment: @ParulChourasia Completed reaper setup. Let me know if you need any help.